# Why does my ground pour cover up everything else? (Eagle)

Tags: eaglecad

- Platform: Mac OS X 10.13.5
- Eagle Version: 9.1.1

For some reason, when I apply my ground pour (draw polygon with name GND and hit ratsnest), the ground pour covers my other components as well as air wires in the Eagle board view.

I don't think I experienced this with other board designs.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Edit:
This is what it looks like in an Eagle tutorial:
[image]

Comment: Looks normal to me. What were you expecting?

Comment: @brhans please see edited post

Comment: To me, it looks like you had put all components on the bottom layer instead of the top layer. Your PCB is upside down. See the BERG label on your USB connector. It's mirrored.

Comment: @Janka thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to be the case since when I click on "hide" for "tPlace", they disappear. Also, these components were placed by default from the beginning by Eagle brd file.

Comment: Please check the layer you poured on then. Maybe it's not top copper but top cream or something like that.

Comment: I think a tight clearance & low-resolution pic are making it look like the pour is connected to pads it shouldn't be and actually isn't. You can see where it is properly connected to pads by the 'reliefs'. As for the 'air wires' - they're not 'real' - there's no copper to prevent the pour from being there. I'm confused as to why you've poured the ground plane before routing anything else ... ?

Comment: @janka yes just checked the layer is "top" since I can hide it when hiding top layer

Comment: @brhans I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCTs0mNXY24&t=678s which pours the ground plane before anything else. I'm assuming it would be easier since you wouldn't have to route the gnd signals

Comment: Select DRC from the tools bar then check for the spacing between wires, vias, bads and holes.

Comment: That only makes any sense if the entire layer on one side of the board is used for your ground plane.

Comment: @brhans please see my updated answer - it seems to be a "feature" of the newest eagle cad

Comment: @AhmedM.Zahran please see my updated answer - it seems to be a "feature" of the newest eagle cad

Comment: The air wires are connections not routed yet. It does not make sense to isolate them from a ground pour. Do the routing first and then add a ground pour. At least route 1 or 2 air wires to see the effect on ground pour. Ground pour requires to set the isolation distance before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known, reported bug, first seen over [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/eagle-9-1-1-the-top-layer-is-on-top-of-the-tplace-layer/td-p/8161025).

Until a fix is issued in a future update, the only work around by now is running this command in the command line of Eagle:

```
set Option.LayerSequence 23 1 16
```

Comment: AWESOME IM GLAD IM NOT CRAZY

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the shape for the ground pour was named GND
Then hit the ratsnets command.

[image]

Comment: confirmed that is what i have. still not working :\

Comment: @AllenHoung what setting do you have for `isolate`? If it 0, as shown in the screenshot above, then of course it will cover everything. Isolate is the clearance between the plane and any other traces/pads/planes.

Comment: @ConcernedCitizen, you might want to use sensible settings in your screenshots.

Comment: @TomCarpenter such as? Having isolate as 0 gives me no issues when i hit ratsnets. It will default to your DRC settings...

Comment: @TomCarpenter what's your value for isolate?

Comment: @ConcernedCitizen please see my updated answer - it seems to be a "feature" of the newest eagle cad

Answer (score 0):

So after trying routing, it seems like this is a new feature in the latest eagle? It seems that eagle will only highlight the specific airwire that you are trying to route as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Or watch some more videos.

Comment: @Uwe it's a bug! see solution